# Using RANDBETWEEN with NORMINV

Tags: excel, random, excel-2007, mean, standard-deviation

I am trying to generate a series of random values ranging from a lower limit of `5` to an upper limit of `8`, with mean of `5.5` and standard deviation of `0.67`.

Using this formula:

```
=NORMINV(RANDBETWEEN(5,8),5.5,0.67)
```

I am receiving the `#NUM!` error. Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try:

```
=IF(OR(NORMINV(RAND(),5.5,0.67)<5,NORMINV(RAND(),5.5,0.67)>8),"",NORMINV(RAND(),5.5,0.67))
```

Comment: Thanks! Will tweak my way around there!